# Restore database to new location

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

Although I use SQL Server a lot, I don't do that many database backups. I restored a `backup.bak` file successfully to the original database say `Database1`.

However, I also want to create a new database `Database2` from that same backup file. Through 'Restore Database' - General - Source - I selected the backup file in Device and then changed the database name in the destination group to `Database2`.

However it error-ed giving a message about the log files being in use.

**Note**: when I did it at home, it automatically created the new named log files, yet at work it does not - just errors.

Is it simply a case of going into Files page and manually renaming the Rows Data' and 'Log' file to match the name of my new database `Database2`?

Do I have to do anything in the options page?

I don't want to cause any changes to the original database `Database1` when creating the new copy of the database.

Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to "accidentally" do anything to the SQL Server data/log files while the service is running unless you force it; while they're in use you can't write/delete them. Like you said in the post, you need to specify different file names for both the data and log files, as they can't be the same as the other copy.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE [Database2] FROM DISK = 'c:\mssql\backup\Database1_Full.bak'
WITH Replace,
MOVE 'Database1' TO 'c:\mssql\data\Database2.mdf',
MOVE 'Database1_Log' TO 'c:\mssql\Database2_Log.ldf';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MOVE like this:

```
USE [master]
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [Database2] FROM DISK = 'c:\mssql\backup\Database1_Full.bak'
WITH CHECKSUM,
MOVE 'Database1_Data' TO 'c:\mssql\data\Database2_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'Database1_Log' TO 'c:\mssql\Database2_Log.ldf',
RECOVERY, STATS = 10;
```